# Ajaxsubmit on angular 2

Tags: angular

I am starting to develop with Angular 2, with previous knowledge in AngularJS.
How can I use [$.ajaxSubmit()](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or similar to submit a form using AJAX without using default form submit? The question is focused on uploading files to a server.

I have used ajaxsubmit with AngularJS before, but haven't found how to do this with Angular 2.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first of all, go to [angular2 documents](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/) and read about Angular2 and how it works in terms of two-way binding. Then, the best source to read about form in ng2 is [Angular2 forms Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

The concept of creating form and working with data in a SPA application, for instance, an Angular2 application, is a bit different from what you have asked in your question.

Some of the main characteristics of forms in angular are :

- The framework support for two-way data binding, change tracking,
  validation, and error handling.
- two-way data bind with [(ngModel)] syntax for reading and writing
  values to input controls
- track the change state and validity of form controls using ngModel in
  combination with a form
- provide strong visual feedback using special CSS classes that track
  the state of the controls
- display validation errors to users and enable/disable form controls

[here is a live template of form in Angular2](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/forms/ts/plnkr.html)

So, Please go ahead and read a bit and follow the guide and then if you have any problem while building your own form, feel free to add here and ask your question.Please include your sample form code somewhere like plnkr.co

Comment: Thanks, I'll read all your suggestins, and I lust say that my question is more focused on upload files to server as I do it with ajaxsubmit. I must being more clear. Thanks again.